# Iterating over the full range of an integer type

Tags: c++, iteration

My first question is, what is the best way to iterate over the entire range of possible values for a particular type? There seems to be no really clean way to accomplish this.

Comment: Why does clean matter if you can  accomplish it? Is this a problem you  have tried and  have a problem with or some other issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an unsigned integral type,

```
unsigned x = 0;
do {
    // something with x
} while (++x > 0);
```

You can do this because unsigned integral types obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n.

For a signed integral type, something like this would work, though it's a bit less clean:

```
int x = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
while (true) {
    // do something with x
    if (x == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) break;
    x++;
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, just noticed. What about short circuiting? `do { something(x); } while( x != max && (++x, true) );`.

Answer (score 3):

For an integer type `T` you can use

```
const T i0 = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
const T in = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

for(T i=i0;i!=in;++i) do_something(i);
do_something(in);
```

Floating point types are a bit trickier. IEEE754 defines an operation that allows you to step to the next representable number above (or below) any given value, but as far as I'm aware there isn't a standard C++ function that exposes it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I'm still pre C++11. Damn good news that I can look forward to it being available when I upgrade my compiler!

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a small type can be done by first converting to a larger type that has a larger size.   Easy. (Note, `long long` is almost always larger than `int`, but is *not* guaranteed to be.)

```
for(long long i = INT_MIN; i<=INT_MAX; ++i) 
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, seperate the last one out:

```
for(int i=INT_MIN; i<INT_MAX; ++i)
    do_thing(i);
do_thing(INT_MAX); //get the last one
```

If you want to iterate over a large type (long long or unsigned long long), I'd have to wonder what you're doing, because that would take something on the order of four hundred years to simply iterate, much less *do* anything with them (assuming a 3.0GHz single core processor).  Iterating over the 64bit range with the worlds fastest supercomputer Tianhe-2 would take ~12 days.

Comment: Going from uint32_t to uint64_t just for that one case where the value is exactly equal to UINT_MAX doesn't seem very elegant. I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @Chris_F: I consider it fairly elegant really.  No extra code, no weird end conditions, just a different type for `i`.  Pretty simple.  I don't think you're going to find anything better outside of a custom counting iterator.

Comment: That last para is **not unrelated** at all?

Comment: Is `long long` guaranteed to be larger than `int`?

Comment: @dyp: I'll mention it

Comment: @MooingDuck You can use `std::numeric_limits::max()` and `min()` to get the min and max values representable by the respective integral type (notice there is a `lowest` for floating point numbers). Converting to a "largest" number is, if not silly, at least not elegant or easy (largest ? in which implementation?). What would you do when reaching the largest integral type ? Traverse with doubles ?

Comment: @MooingDuck One may want to implement a **stateful infinite loop**, where she can probe for number of iterations .. hence looping over a large integral type